# SafeValue must use [property]=binding, but IT IS

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello all, this is driving me nuts. I tried all the fixes I was able to find online and nothing seems to work.

I am loading the base64 image info from a DB, which returns the base64 encoded image, like this:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/4UHuRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABgEaAAUAAAABAAAAVgEbAAUAAAABAAAAXgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAITAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAIcuocAAcAAAgMAAAAZgAAEOQAAAEsAAAAAQAAASwAAAABHOoAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...
```

Then in my TS file I have the following function:

```
photo_url(data:string){

     this.user_photo = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data).toString();

}
```

My HTML file looks as follows:

```
<img [src]="user_photo ? user_photo : 'assets/img/default.png'">
```

However I am getting the following error and the image is not displaying:

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value SafeValue must use [property]=binding: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/4UHuRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABgEaAAUAAAABAAAAVgEbAAUAAAABAAAAXgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAITAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAIcuocAAcAAAgMAAAAZgAAEOQAAAEsAAAAAQAAASwAAAABHOoAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...
```

Error says sanitizer should uses property binding, and it is, but it is still showing that error and the image does not display.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use `.toString` you are setting `user_photo` to a string instead of a `SafeResourceUrl` as required.

Actually simply removing the `.toString()` will make this work properly. Otherwise you are essentially just undoing the work of the DomSanitizer.

```
user_photo: SafeResourceUrl;
photo_url(data: string){
     this.user_photo = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
       'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data);
}
```

Comment: blob data of image is not working in IE when refreshing using button click....

Comment: i tried same but not working in my case